# generic patch for all Operating System(Linux, Windows, Mac)

Tags: linux, windows, patch

I've created a patch using the diff utility in Windows 7. However, when I'm applying the patch in Linux, it is failing(hunk failure). My intuition says that this is most probably because of the fact that each OS treats Line Breaks and Carriage returns differently leading to failure of patch application.

My question: Is it possible(is there any open source utility may be?) that can help me make a generic patch for different operating system?

Thanks,

Comment: If your assumption is right, passing the patch file through the dos2unix utility should solve your problem. Have you tried that?

Comment: That will work most probably(I haven't tried that by the way), but that doesn't meet the criterion for "generic" or does it?

Comment: What about using [the -w option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)? If it's the line endings that might help. On the other hand, I got so fed up with that line ending nonsense that I switched to using unix style line endings everywhere - most editors can do that. That might also be a solution?